# SwiftUI Toolbar, Tabview & TabBarItem is not behaving as I would expect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When adopting NavigationStack with a TabView embedded, then using a Toolbar and ToolbarItems, I get unexpected behaviour when switching between tabs.

Expectation: I should be able to have different ToolbarItems depending on which tab is selected and when switching between tabs, the ToolbarItem in the position I specify per tab should change.

Behaviour: The ToolbarItems append to the specified position as you move across each tab.

```
    @State var selectedIndex: Int
    @State var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
                    Group {
                        TextView(tabName: .constant("Home"))
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                            }
                            .tag(1)
                        TextView(tabName: .constant("Contacts"))
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Contacts", systemImage: "person.3")
                            }
                            .tag(1)
                        TextView(tabName: .constant("Settings"))
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape")
                            }
                            .tag(1)
                    }
                    .toolbarBackground(Color.red)
                    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
                    .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for the view for each tab (this is a simplified example, I have tried using seperate views but get the same behaviour);

```
    @Binding var tabName: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tab \(tabName)")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        print("Profile ")
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    }

                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Tab 1]
[Screenshot of Tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ptht.png)
[image: Screenshot of Tab 3]

I can't find any information in the developer docs on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you try removing the `tag()` method or give them unique identifier?

Comment: You are reusing your view (`TextView`) for every tab with different parameters. Even though parameters are different, view is the same, so same toolbar items are added. Use separate views.

Comment: As stated in the question the behaviour is the same with separate views. This code is a stripped down version of a larger app which uses separate views.

Comment: As you have a navigation stack the toolbar is associated to it, not to the tabview. Trying to have one toolbar in view inside the tab confuse SwiftUI . The toolbar should be associated to the tabview . Also, usually it is not good to put a tabview in a navigation stack : navigation stack are more likely to be in each tab.

Comment: @PtitXav This problem started by us trying to have a NavigationStack per each TabView but TabView didn't work in this case?

Comment: Having NavigationStatck/TabView/NavigationStack is a bad idea as you can not know which navigation stack you are in (Main one or Tab one). So the SwiftUi also. If you want navigation stack in each tab, remove the top navigation stack. May be your design should be rethink.